# Small Caps not Working

Tags: polyglossia

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=14in,left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry} %margins
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx,fixltx2e,graphicx,polyglossia,fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\begin{document}
\textsc{This is written in small caps}
\end{document}
```

This problem with this code is that the text is not written in small caps.
Along with this how can i use "Times" font in polyglossia?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but does have alphabets/fonts used for urdu language small caps at all in general?

Comment: Urdu language does not have small caps and the text i want in small caps is in English not in Urdu

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test your example directly, since Times New Roman is not installed on my computer and I am also no expert in `XeLaTeX` at all, so I can only guess... the font you specified does not provide for small caps at all or the syntax for `XeLaTeX` is different, i.e. not `\textsc` or `\scshape`

Comment: Is the urdu part relevant to the question? I commented that out and surprisingly i have a TMR. But: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 8.`

Answer (score 9):

A problem with XeLaTeX is that it will use the font that your operating system recognizes as “Times New Roman” and there are several variants thereof around. In my experience, the feature most of these variants share is the lack of small caps letters.

A clone of Times that has small caps and is available on TeX Live and MiKTeX is TeX Gyre Termes; its coverage of small caps letters is limited to the Latin Alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Abc \textsc{Small Caps}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the most recent version of `fontspec`, the syntax of the command has become

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]
```

(I'm not sure I like this form of input.)

Comment: "(I'm not sure I like this form of input.)" I don't like it either! Inverting the order of required and optional arguments of `\setmainfont` is going to break a lot of programs. I wonder what made the authors of `fontspec` implement this change.

Comment: @Mico The old syntax is still understood.

Comment: Thanks. That's good news. (The latest `fontspec` manual doesn't mention the old syntax, so I had assumed it was no longer valid.)

Comment: @Mico Making the old syntax invalid would break thousands of existing documents!

Comment: @egreg I don't know much about the old syntax or the new syntax but if there is a better way to do all this then do tell me

Comment: @egreg Why it doesn't work for me? I just use `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` instead of your `\setmainfont{...}`, and then the problem seems to be solved. But I'm not sure this font is the same as Times New Roman.

Comment: @Hyden The code works under the assumption you have a system font called “Times New Roman”.

Comment: The small caps doesn't work for me with this example. I get `Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Letters=SmallCaps' (smcp) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'TeX Gyre Termes' with script ''
(fontspec)                and language ''.`

Comment: @Viesturs Do you have TeX Gyre Termes installed as a system font?

Comment: No! ! `Package fontspec Error: The font "Tex Gyre Termes" cannot be found.`

Comment: @Viesturs Do you see the font in the font menus for other applications?