# Times New Roman and small caps

Tags: fonts, typography

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fontspec} %compile with xelatex
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}                                                                                                                                                                              
\begin{document}
\textsc{Small Caps}
\end{document}
```

No small caps are obtained when I uncomment the line `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`. There is a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

How to both have Times New Roman font style and small caps?

Comment: The line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %compile with xelatex` seems strange, you should never use `inputenc` with xelatex (it does nothing other than give a warning that it should not be used)

Comment: On windows it works fine (without the inputenc which is wrong). times.ttf has small caps.

Comment: It works on windows as Ulrike says, or you could use a clone font such as TeX Gyre Termes

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I work in Ubuntu. I downloaded separately the Times New Roman font. Perhaps, I need to do a special download of small caps?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what is meant by a clone font? How to use the Tex Gyre Termes?

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187398/4427

Comment: In windows the small caps are in the times.ttf. I don't know if there exist a free font usable in ubuntu. To use tex gyre see egreg's link.

Comment: use `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't have `Tex Gyre Termes` installed. `! Package fontspec Error: The font "Tex Gyre Termes" cannot be found.` How to install it?

Comment: That is part of texlive or miktex so you should be able to just use your tex system package updater unlike times new roman which is a font that you have to pay for (but comes with windows)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , I am using already a very new version `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.11.18)  16 JAN 2019 19:11`. Do I still need some additional update?

Comment: TeX Gyre fonts have been in texlive for years so you don't need a new one but you presumably didn't choose a full installation, try `tlmgr install tex-gyre`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't have `tlmgr`. How to install it? I installed TexLive from here https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: you do have tlmgr if you got texlive from there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a problem on Macs as well as Linux. Newer versions of Times New Roman have small capitals as well as lowercase/old-style numerals as OpenType features. Unfortunately, other operating systems still tend to distribute older versions. The version of Times New Roman bundled with macOS, 5.01.3x, doesn't include small caps; but Office for Mac has version 7.00, which includes the newer OpenType features.

Alternatively, as already suggested in the comments, you could use the TeX Gyre Termes clone of Times:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Small Caps}
\end{document}
```